# I want to display what Im currently listening to on my personal website

Tags: deezer

I dont want to have to sign into deezer everyday, I want my account to automatically display what song Im listening to on my website whenever I play anything.

What do I have to do to set this up?

I had a look at the oauth api but its not very clear how to utilize it for this kind of permanent connection.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the REST API and the user/history endpoint (http://developers.deezer.com/api/user/history). What you can do is to get the access_token from the API explorer if you want (http://developers.deezer.com/api/explorer?url=user/me/history) et use it to get all the informations about your listening history with a request. Just be sure not to make available or visible your access_token.